# How to set context path in Tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, war, tomcat8

I have a war file named `FooBar.war`, now I want to set context path "/" point to this web apps. It means Users can access the webapp via URL: `localhost:8080/` 
To do that I add a file called `ROOT.xml` in `<catalina_home>/conf/Catalina/localhost/`with content

```
<Context docBase="/opt/mywebapps/FooBar" path="" reloadable="true" />
```

And I also put `FooBar.war` into folder `/opt/mywebapps/`
then set all permissions for this folder:

```
chmod -R 777 /opt/mywebapps/
```

After starting Tomcat server, the server can not deploy the war file:

```
1-Apr-2019 11:33:36.211 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:629)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@6023aae1]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4932)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5067)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/opt/mywebapps/FooBar] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:706)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 13 more
```

If you have any ideas to fix it, please help me.

Comment: IMO it's much simpler to just rename your war to ROOT.war

Comment: @SvetlinZarev: Thank you so much! I followed your way. It works now. But do you know the reason why the error happened in my way?

Comment: You should resolve the `resource set specified [/opt/mywebapps/FooBar] is not valid` exception before understating why you can't reach your app using `localhost:8080/`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595104/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-the-main-resource-set-specified-is-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <Context docBase="/opt/mywebapps/FooBar" path="" reloadable="true" />
> ```
>
> And I also put FooBar.war into folder /opt/mywebapps/

Note that you now have `/opt/mywebapps/FooBar.war`, while you're referencing `/opt/mywebapps/FooBar`. (note the difference in ".war")

As you're not in Tomcat's own webapps folder, where (with the default configuration) WAR files will be automatically unzipped, Tomcat just signals that the location that you've configured simply doesn't exist.

Comment: Got it, Tomcat can not extract FooBar.war in `/opt/mywebapps/`. I tried to put FooBar into `/opt/mywebapps/`. It works. Is there any way to config Tomcat can extract war file outside Tomcat root context?

Comment: "can not" vs "does not": If you want an "exploded war file" there, e.g. the directory: Put it there. But Tomcat itself doesn't need it: Tomcat is happy with a WAR file, you'll just need to configure the correct file name. If your application dynamically changes the content of the directory, you should stop that immediately - it's building maintenance hell and almost guarantees that you can't have a proper disaster recovery. Just configure your context with the war file name, and you're set. Or unzip it yourself (war is just a glorified zip format)