# Tomcat mapping context via server.xml is not working in Tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, tomcat8, tomcat8.5

I have define web directory path in docBase so that tomcat directly access files and run it.
My web directory path is 'D:\Test\WebContent' where Test is my project name.
I am declaring context tag under Host tag in server.xml file of tomcat.

After start tomcat whenever I hit URL 'http://localhost:8080/Test' get error HTTP Status 404 – Not Found.
I am using Tomcat 8.5

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="true">
<Context path="/Test" docBase="D:\Test\WebContent" reloadable="true" />
</Host>
```

Comment: See if this helps.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55448206/how-to-set-context-path-in-tomcat-8

Comment: I don't have any war file. I want direct access webContent folder of project

Comment: You stated unpackWars="true"  and you dont have any wars?  Try  setting it to false.

Comment: I have tried it just now but still getting 404 error. If I use war file then its working fine but when I try to direct access webContent then I am getting this error.

Comment: Try setting autoDeploy=false as well

Comment: tried it but still getting same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230121/discussion-between-susan-mustafa-and-rahul).